# How can i see/log all requests coming from a registration form (not from the UI)?

Tags: plugins, wp-query, forms, security, request-filter

I am talking about the REGISTER form

PROBLEM: I have some requests that are coming from somewhere else - not from the user interface. I know this, because these requests don't have all the mandatory fields completed - and this can't be done from the user interface, because of the data validations (for example, you can't submit the form without a name, or without a valid email address)

I suppose this is a security vulnerability, and I've heard someone can gain admin access through these requests.

QUESTION: Is there any way(a plugin maybe) I can log and parse these requests, in order to understand who/what/why/how is creating them?
MORE EXPLANATIONS if needed: each time a user submits this register form, I get an email with details (name, email, period, choosen price). But sometimes, i get emails without all the mandatory details: for example: an email with no price or with no email... and this is theoretically not possible. how are these made, and why? is there any way to log these and see WHERE are they coming from?

Comment: This is Contact Form 7. 3rd party plugins are off-topic. [Contact the developer](http://contactform7.com/support/).

Comment: Someone is sending spam using your `Contact Form 7` form. You don't really have any control over this. Usually spammers hijack servers and use them for sending spams so practically you cannot block these submissions. But instead you can try to identify legit submission from bogus submissions. One solution would be to check refer url. Usually spam bots do not have any refer URL so you can block such requests or emails. `Contact Form 7` have Akismet integration that you can use. Third, you can install a captcha too. You will not get more help for this plugin here since it's 3rd party plugin.

Comment: thanks a lot! but are these spams getting to me automatically and random, or someone is targeting specifically my website? AND how can i check for the refer url, because I'm not getting it in the emails? thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could use "**save_post**" hook to capture all submit within WP, for ex:

```
function just_got_you( $post_id ) {
    if ($post_id != '123')
        return;

    << do your logging stuff here >>

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'just_got_you', 10, 2 );
```

Change 123 to your page/post id. More reference here [Save Post Hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

Comment: where should this function be added?